# 90s space-based shoot-em-up vertical scroller PC game

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm looking for a space-based vertical scroller PC game that uses 2.5d sprites and was released in the mid-to-late 90s (though I'm still unsure about this)

The features of this game include:

- You are in a human-controlled spaceship fighting alien ships that are arranged in a Space-Invaders like formation and shoot down at you. There are different types of enemies based on the boss that you will face. The enemies come from the top down into the top half of the screen but can sometimes go further down.
- After defeating all of the enemy ships, you fight a giant boss spaceship. The levels that you pick show the boss that you will face, the types of enemies, and the weapons that you can use
- When the main character dies, there is an explosion, screaming noise, and you can see the pilot ejecting to the left of the ship.

Comment: Most of these details feel very generic. Can you think of anything else? Color schemes? Interesting weapons? To what degree the enemy shots covered the screen? Was this on Steam? Downloaded from a site? Shareware disks?

Comment: See if it might be Galaga or a version of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvjapcHsqXY

Comment: Can you remember anything about the plot? Who were the aliens, who were the pilots?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: unsure about colour schemes. The enemy's shots can potentially fill the screen depending on which kind of enemy you are facing. This game was made before Steam came around and I remember it being on a CD

Comment: @jo1storm it is very similar to Galaga in the gameplay aspect but has better graphics and sound effects

Comment: @Valorum I don't believe there was a story or lore to the game at all. The aliens weren't visible; they only existed in the form of their spaceships. There was only one pilot that you play as.

Comment: Just because it's one of the more popular schmups, have you looked at the *Tyrian* games? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_(video_game)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots getting there! I don't believe it had that much customisation and as varied/diverse an environment (it only stayed in space), but yes it is that type of game (vertical scroller)

Comment: There's a game called Alien Sky and Star Defender 4 that are VERY similar in terms of interface and gameplay. When I say 2.5d sprites, I mean the exact style used in the former game.

I also found a thread on Reddit that describes this game perfectly but didn't have an answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/970cso/tomtgamepc_game_that_is_similar_to_space/

Comment: Maybe one of the Raiden games? https://youtu.be/j_cHFoDOA74 That game is from the early 90s, are the graphics comparable?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [LaserAge](https://www.mobygames.com/game/laserage). Possibly [Cosmic Ambush](https://www.mobygames.com/game/cosmic-ambush).

Others that don't fit as well for various reasons, but are still possibilities: [Overkill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverKill_(video_game)), [Raptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raptor:_Call_of_the_Shadows), [Tyrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_(video_game)), [DemonStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DemonStar), [Major Stryker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Stryker), [Aliens](https://www.mobygames.com/game/aliens____), [Galactix](https://www.mobygames.com/game/galactix), [Star Defender](https://www.mobygames.com/game/star-defender), [FreeStrike](https://www.mobygames.com/game/freestrike), [Swarm](https://www.mobygames.com/game/swarm__), [Avenger](https://www.mobygames.com/game/avenger___).